# To investigate the convergence of integrals

Tags: convergence-divergence

I want to investigate the convergence of integral

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{- x^{4} + 1}}\, dx$$

How shall I deal with it? I thought about taking $\frac{1}{x^p}$ and finding $p$ by $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. Now I decided to use $\frac{1}{(1-x)^p}$, but how shall I do with finding $p$?

And others: $\int\limits_1^2 \frac{1}{\ln x}\, dx$
$\int\limits_{n/2}^\infty \sin x\frac{1}{x^2}\, dx$

How should I deal with them, just an idea please

Comment: The first apparently takes into use the Gamma function

Comment: The second diverges, and I would use a comparison to $1/x$, perhaps change it to $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln(x+1)}dx$, and then use taylor series to show how it is always greater than $1/x$, and $1/x$ diverges in that range

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean for the third

Comment: For the third, I would suggest using a u-sub for $1/x = u$, which will give a function that I believe will always numerically converge (given non-infinite values of n)

Comment: @JohnLou, thank you, man, i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let x=$\frac1y\implies dx=-\frac1{y^2}dy$ then

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{- x^{4} + 1}}\, dx=\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]y}{y\sqrt[3]{y^{4} - 1}}\, dy$$

and thus since

$$ \frac{\sqrt[3]y}{y\sqrt[3]{y^{4} - 1}}\sim \frac1{y^2}$$

the integral converges by limit comparison test with $\int \frac1{y^2}$.

Comment: Nice solution +1. Do you have any idea how to find the actual value for this one?

Comment: @JohnLou Thanks, no I’ve not idea how to evaluate it!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @TaumCkBep You are welcome! Bye

Comment: The actual value can be computed by enforcing the substitution $x^4=u$, then invoking Euler's Beta function. It depends on $\Gamma(1/3)$ and $\Gamma(1/4)$ and it is numerically close to $7/6$.